# JSONObject contains escape characters

Tags: java, json

I'm building a simulator to post JSON data to a service I'm running.

The JSON should look like this:

```
{"sensor":
       {"id":"SENSOR1","name":"SENSOR","type":"Temperature","value":100.12,"lastDateValue":"\/Date(1382459367723)\/"}
}
```

I tried this with the "Advanced REST Client" in Chrome and this works fine. The date get's parsed properly by the ServiceStack webservice.

So, the point is to write a sensor simulator that posts data like this to the web service.

I created this in Java, so I could run it on my raspberry pi.

This is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url = "http://localhost:63003/api/sensors";
    String sensorname = "Simulated sensor";
    int currentTemp = 10;
    String dateString = "\\" + "/Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ")\\" + "/";
    System.out.println(dateString);

    System.out.println("I'm going to post some data to: " + url);

    //Creating the JSON Object
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("id", sensorname);
    data.put("name", sensorname);
    data.put("type", "Temperature");
    data.put("value", currentTemp);
    data.put("lastDateValue", dateString);
    JSONObject sensor = new JSONObject().put("sensor",  data);

    //Print out the data to be sent
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    sensor.write(out);

    String jsonText = out.toString();
    System.out.print(jsonText);

    //Sending the object
    HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost p = new HttpPost(url);
    p.setEntity(new StringEntity(sensor.toString(), ContentType.create("application/json")));

    try {
        HttpResponse r = c.execute(p);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output of this program is as follows:

```
\/Date(1382459367723)\/
I'm going to post some data to: http://localhost:63003/api/sensors
{"sensor":{"lastDateValue":"\\/Date(1382459367723)\\/","id":"Simulated sensor","name":"Simulated sensor","value":10,"type":"Temperature"}}
```

The issue here is that the JSONObject string still contains these escape characters. But when I print the string in the beginning it does not contain the escape characters. Is there any way to get rid of these? My service can't parse these..

This is a sample of what I send with the rest client in chrome:

```
 {"sensor":{"id":"I too, am a sensor!","name":"Willy","type":"Temperature","value":100.12,"lastDateValue":"\/Date(1382459367723)\/"}}
```

Comment: If your service can't parse escaped characters then isn't that a bug in the service? Fix the parser instead of trying to generate incorrect JSON.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not my service implementation. I'm using ServiceStack WCF Services. So I can't really fix this. I mean, if the string is represented in the correct way, how come JSONObject puts 'em there ?

Comment: Try using unicode for these escape characters while constructing date string and see if service is able to interpret the result. The unicodes are  \  ==> `\u005c`   and  /  ==>  `\u002f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONObject` is correctly encoding the string. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals) describes how string literals are to be escaped in JavaScript (and, by extension, JSON). The following note is important to understanding what happens in your example:

> For characters not listed in Table 2.1, a preceding backslash is ignored, but this usage is deprecated and should be avoided.

Your example (`"\/Date(1382459367723)\/"`) uses a preceding backslash before a `/`. Because `/` is not in table 2.1, the `\` should simply be ignored. If your service doesn't ignore the `\`, then it either has a bug, or is not a JSON parser (perhaps it uses a data format which is similar to, but not quite, JSON).

Since you need to generate non-conforming JSON, you won't be able to use standard tools to do so. Your two options are to write your own not-quite-JSON encoder, or to avoid characters which must be escaped, such as `\` and `"`.

Comment: Note that RFC 8259, the latest version of the JSON specification, now allows backslash to appear before slash in string literals.

Answer (score 1):

@pburka is correct. If you want to send it in `\/Date(1382459367723)\/` format, try  escaping the blackslash twice as below

```
String dateString = "\\\\" + "/Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ")\\\\" + "/";
```

In the first pass, dateString will make it as `\\/Date(1382459367723)\\/` and finally JSONObject will add extra backslashes internally to it's buffer i.e `\\\/Date(1382459367723)\\\/` so that the blackslashes before / will be ignored according to JSON parsing rules and you would get the desired result i.e `\/Date(1382459367723)\/`