# JSONObject getString returns wrong string

Tags: android, json

In one of my Android projects, I hit a web service and as a response I get a simple key value pair like

```
{"CHECKSUM":"8d40oGKDPqs8sBAd6ky9tF40h\/111XaDKpqR\/Bzme17="}
```

but when I try to read it via `JSONObject.getString("CHECKSUM")` method it omits backward slash characters and returns the remaining string.

Is this a bug in `JSONObject` implementation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609205/jsonobject-contains-escape-characters

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct implementation of JSONObject.getString.  The backslashes are being read as an escape character for the forward slashes.  If for some reason it is imperative that you get the backlashes as part of your response, you would need your backend web developers to change the response from `"\/"` to `"\\\/"`

Comment: change the response from "\ /" to "\/" what changes have you made??

Comment: Oops! S.O. auto-formatted the text so my escape characters were lost. I've updated my answer to show how they would need to escape the backslash as well.